# Updating state of a class inside a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of this class with the array of objects stored in the variable `childData`. However, when I use `setState({childData: childData)}`, and use it later on by calling `this.state.childData`, it is `undefined`, so it never updates the states with the information.

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    state = {
        childData: ""
    }

   retrieve = () => {
       let childData;
       var leadsRef = database.ref('users');
       leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
           childData = snapshot.val();
           console.log(childData)
           this.setState({
               childData: childData
           })
       });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieve()
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>These are all the users in the app</h3>
            {console.log(this.state.childData)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

Comment: What's being logged on `console.log(childData)` inside `leadsRef.on('value'`

Comment: an array of two objects with two users' information. When I comment out this.setState(childData: childData), that is what I get. However, when I leave that setState(childData:childData), I don't get the state to update AND get that same thing (the array of two objects over 50 times) and this error message <Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.>

Comment: The only reason you are having an issue is that the value of this is different when you use function instead of an arrow function. The answer works because it’s using an arrow function, otherwise your solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on. First, you do indeed need to set state within the callback function. However, as is, you'll hit an infinite loop. That's because you shouldn't be performing the async function in the `render` method. Instead, do it in the `componentDidMount` method so it only fires when the component mounts.

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    state = {
        childData: ""
    }

   retrieve = () => {
       let childData;
       var leadsRef = database.ref('users');
       leadsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
           childData = snapshot.val();
           console.log(childData)
           this.setState({
               childData: childData
           })
       });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieve()
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>These are all the users in the app</h3>
            {console.log(this.state.childData)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

Comment: I tried this, and the value is still undefined in the return statement this.state.childData

Comment: You saw where I moved `setState` to?

Comment: Sorry, an extra `setState` got into my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: I only see one setState in the code, it still doesn't work

Comment: @JoscandyNunez I made an update to change to an arrow function in the callback to make sure `this` is referring to the component.

Comment: the change to the arrow function worked ! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting state inside the leadsRef.on callback function. For example:

```
leadsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    const childData = snapshot.val()
    this.setState({childData})
})
```

Comment: I tried that, and I get this error <TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null>

Comment: when I add it there, it gives me this error <TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null>

Answer (score 0):

Use this.setState in your callback. The code you are executing is non blocking so this.setState will be executed before you retrieved childDate.

Also make you callback function an arrow function.

Is this helpfull, I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: If you make it an arrow function, does it work then?

Comment: it did ! also called this.retrieve()  in componentDidMount() , thank you!